# AddConfiguration where comes from?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

On net core 2.0 there is a call to AddConfiguration like this:

```
logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
```

https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs

I am trying to create my own custom CreateDefaultBuilder but I dont know which assemblies to include to have AddConfiguration available.

For now I had to include the following packages.. but some one is missed

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets         
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel                    
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json                
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection               
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug                     
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging                           
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions   
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console                   
Microsoft.NETCore.App                                  
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine         
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https              
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
```

Comment: Is it by chance [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggingbuilderextensions.addconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.1) (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ivan

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration
```

Solved the issue